# Visual Studio 2010 does not follow my CSS ... help pls

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2010

here is my CSS:

```
.body
{
     font-family : Segoe UI;
}

.table{
    width : 50%;
    font-size:medium;
    border-spacing:5px;       
}

.leftCol
{
    width:15%
}

.RightCol
{
    width:35%
}

.header
{
    width:35%;
    font-weight:900;
    text-align:left;
}

.dates
{
    color:GrayText;   
    font-size:small
}

.pictures
{
    width:10%;
}

.userName
{
    width:10%;
    text-align:left;

}

.smallTable
{
    width:20%;    
}
```

Here is the HTML markup:

```
 <table class=".table">
                                <tr>
                                    <td rowspan="3" class=".leftCol">
                                        <asp:Label ID="ImageLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Image") %>' />
                                    </td>
                                    <td class=".header">
                                         <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserName") %>' />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class=".rightCol">
                                        <asp:Label ID="TextLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Text") %>' />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class=".dates">
                                       <asp:Label ID="DateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Date") %>' />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table><hr />
```

the other one:(this table width actually works)

```
<table class=".smallTable">
                                <tr >
                                    <td class=".pictures">
                                       <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Pictures") %>' /></td>
                                    <td class=".userName" align="left">
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' /></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table><hr />
```

so, instead of following the rules, VS uses 100% width for the table using .table class, and then it just arranges in justified. The dates does not appear in gray colour ... and basically nothing follows. But i can assure you that the class names i wrote and everything is correct as i check. It just doesnt work . Do you know anyway i can force VS 2010 to do this ?

Comment: What do you mean in _blaming_ Visual Studio, what does this have to do with the output?

Comment: If it doesn't work then something is not correct :) have you attached the stylesheet correctly?

Comment: Post your HTML markup as well. You are also using a class of .table whereas a table element already exists.

Comment: As answered by Aristos, take out the dots in your markup. Also don't use .table as class name!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all class that you declare on the tags you must **place them with out the dot**. Eg:

```
<table class="smallTable">
```

and change the class name `.table` to something else because the table is reserve for all tables and probably this type of variables lead to bugs. Do not mix up the tag names with the css declare.

The css `table{ width : 50%; }` change all the tables on the page.
The css `body{ font-family : Segoe UI; }` change all the body fonts.
The css `.body{ font-family : Segoe UI; }` is change only what you declare on class as body but eventually can lead to bugs and errors .

Comment: @Jawad No its not work, or VS maybe show it as work, they just have a width. You think that works, or browser have some tolerant on some of them, but its not work, its not correct.

Comment: so .smallTable { width:20%; } does not get applied?

Comment: @Jawad Its apply if you declare it as class="smallTable"